# dd wrt firmwire file prompt password while extracting

Tags: networking, router, telnet, firmware, dd-wrt

Last day i download

a dd wrt firmware `dd-wrt.v24-21676_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini-e900.bin` for

Linksys E 900 router. I need to extract this image for development.

i try to extract this file using 7zip but it's ask password.

[image]

I can't see any password in the documentation. is any default password

for extract this image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons such zip files are password-protected:

1. Someone doesn't want you to have access to it.
2. To bypass spamware/malware filters. In this case, the bypassing makes it suspect. A quick google search indicates there are plenty of firmwares out there from official sites. Why do they password-protect the firmware?? Hrm.

The password mechanism on zip files is not cryptographically secure. Brute-force password crackers should do the job in a day at most. Apparently there are several for that task.

Comment: :( ... you mean customization is not possible in this firmware. Thank you for your valuable reply

Comment: Uh, I didn't mean that at all.